# How can I roll out updates to an installed APT package

Tags: apt, deb

I have created an APT package, my APT repo is hosted on an S3 bucket.

The `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/<my-package>.list` entry also points to my S3.

```
deb [arch=all signed-by=<PUBLIC_KEY>] http://<s3-address>/apt-repo stable main
```

Now, say someone has already installed this package, can I force new updates into their system -- when I upload new content to S3?

Is it possible to release updates in already installed APT packages?

Comment: How the content is hosted isn't really relevant; like the URL for the repo reveals, this is just another web site as far as Apt is concernel.

Answer (score 1):

The standard mechanism is to build and publish a package with a higher version number.

You can't force clients to upgrade without their cooperation; perhaps configure them to upgrade all packages on the system nightly (try `apt-cron`).